# How do you generate a histogram in NetLogo?

Tags: netlogo

I have a `breed` called `players`. Each `player-owns` a `player-strategy`. There are 6 possible `player-strategies`. When I write

`histogram [player-strategy] of players`

nothing appears on my plot.

I have one plot with one pen -- and don't set either the plot or penname. `plot-name` returns the plot. `pen-mode` is `bar`. `interval` is 1.0

I don't know how to ask for the current `penname`. But since the plot has only one pen it shouldn't matter.

The histogram command is in both `plot-update` and `pen-update`. I've tried it in both together or one at a time. I also tried in code. Makes no difference.

What do I have to do to get a histogram to appear?

Comment: Are your player strategies numeric?

Comment: No. They are agents.

Comment: Oh, then my proposed solution won't work "as is", because agents can't be keys in a NetLogo `table`. You'll have to add a step to map them to strings...

Comment: Something like: `let counts table:counts [ [ strategy-name ] of player-strategy ] of players`...

Answer (score 10):

OK, here is what I think you are after.

If you create the following plot:

[image: plot setup]

And write the following code:

```
extensions [table]
breed [players player]
players-own [player-strategy]

to setup
  clear-all
  create-players 100 [ set player-strategy one-of ["a" "b" "c" "d" "e"] ]
  reset-ticks
end

to update-strategy-plot
  set-current-plot "Player strategies"
  clear-plot
  let counts table:counts [ player-strategy ] of players
  let strategies sort table:keys counts
  let n length strategies
  set-plot-x-range 0 n
  let step 0.05 ; tweak this to leave no gaps
  (foreach strategies range n [ [s i] ->
    let y table:get counts s
    let c hsb (i * 360 / n) 50 75
    create-temporary-plot-pen s
    set-plot-pen-mode 1 ; bar mode
    set-plot-pen-color c
    foreach (range 0 y step) [ _y -> plotxy i _y ]
    set-plot-pen-color black
    plotxy i y
    set-plot-pen-color c ; to get the right color in the legend
  ])
end
```

You should get the following plot:

[image: plot result]

I believe this should answer [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49100688/487946) as well.

(Note that I've put the plotting code in a code tab procedure, but you could just as well stick it in the "Plot update commands" field.)

Comment: Thank you very much.  Haven't tried it yet, but the result is just what I want. [ A lot more code than I expected :) ]

Comment: Clever but also dismaying.
https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/issues/1586

Comment: The NetLogo development team has limited resources. But NetLogo is open source. Contributions, or money to fund contributions, would always be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I know it is a very old question, but in case anyone lands here on a search. The current version of NetLogo comes with example code for histogram usage: look in the file menu under 'Models Library'; see 'Code Examples'/'Histogram Example'.